# How to get the coordinates of Selenium Mouse cursor Python without involving any elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I need to find a way to get location coordinates of current Selenium ActionChains invisible cursor.

I can find it after I move to an element, and calculate it from size of element and location of element, but this requires to move first to it and is not very accurate.

I can find it injecting javascript to make a div on the cursor to make it visible, and thereby even getting the location of that element, but this is not ideal because it requires that I modify the webpage's html.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You have to add event listener and than get recent mouse pointer.

```
export const setCurrentMousePointerScript = `
window.currentMouseX = null;
window.currentMouseY = null;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  window.currentMouseX = event.pageX;
  window.currentMouseY = event.pageY;
}, true);
`;

export const getCurrentMousePointerScript = `
return {
  x: window.currentMouseX,
  y: window.currentMouseY
};
`;

export const setCurrentMousePointer = (driver: WebDriver) => {
  return driver.executeScript(setCurrentMousePointerScript);
};

export const getCurrentMousePointer = (driver: WebDriver) => {
  return driver.executeScript(getCurrentMousePointerScript);
};
```

You can pin `set` script to current driver instance using `pinScript` method. It won't change between different page loading.

It is up to you how to work with initial position. You can move pointer to `driver.switchTo().activeElement()` immediately. But your initial persistent mouse move may be suspicious from bot detection pointer of view. So it will be better to trigger `mousemove` on random visible element on the page after random amount of time.

Also please make sure your script is hidden:

1. Minify/obfuscate it (so it may not be detected using listing of mousemove event handlers).
2. Use some random dom element as global context instead of `window`.
3. Use random unique names instead of `currentMouseX` and `currentMouseY`.